# Recalculating srcset in vue app, element binding

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to recalculate the srcset on window resize. I have a picture element within my template as follows:

```
<picture>
  <source :srcset="{path-to-image}-lg.jpg" media="(min-width: 800px)">
  <source :srcset="{path-to-image}-md.jpg" media="(min-width: 400px)">
  <img id="my_image" :src="{path-to-image}-sm.jpg">
</picture>
```

with the following eventListener:

```
methods: {
  setSrc () {
    if (!this.selected) return

    let width = window.innerWidth
    let img = document.getElementById('selected_image')
    let fileWithExt = img.src.split('/').pop()
    let filename = fileWithExt.split('.')[0]
    let size = filename.split('-').pop() // all images end in '-sm', '-md', '-lg'
    let picture = img.parentElement

    if (
      (width < 400 && size !== 'sm') ||
      (width >= 400 && width < 800 && size !== 'md') ||
      (width > 800 && size !== 'lg')
    ) {
      let html = picture.outerHTML
      picture.outerHTML = html
    }
  }
},
created () {
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.setSrc)
},
beforeDestroy () {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.setSrc)
}
```

the event listener handles the resizing/media query image selection perfectly, however, what I'm realizing is that replacing the picture's html is replacing an element in the DOM that is bound to vue, with one that is not. So I guess what I'm up against is:

1. Is there a better way of handling the resize to recalculate the srcset with Vue?
2. If this is ultimately the best way to handle the resize, is there a way to rebind the picture element to Vue?

Comment: Can you provide more context please. My understanding is that with a `picture` element and the `srcset` attribute the browser should be able to pick the right image automatically, no?

Comment: On pageload yes, but I'm running into issues on resize, where the image remains the smaller size

Comment: I see. This might be a browser specific thing. Have you seen [this issue](https://github.com/ausi/respimagelint/issues/31)?

Comment: Also I think you can force Vue to re-render the `picture` element if you assign it a `key` that changes at every breakpoint.

Comment: That article mentioned safari, I'm seeing this in chrome on Android (to be clear the resizing issue is occuring when phone orientation changes from portrait to landacape). I'll have to give that multiple key assignment a try and report back! Thanks!

Comment: @HusamIbrahim see the answer I posted. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HusamIbrahim So I wanted to use a native html5 element made for this kind of thing, but since I was going to have to add some event listening to dynamically set a key, I ultimately decided to just handle the whole thing with a v-if, else-if, else

update to template:

```
<img v-if="breakpoint === 800" :src="selected.sizes.xl">
<img v-else-if="breakpoint === 400" :src="selected.sizes.lg">
<img v-else :src="selected.sizes.md">
```

I added the `breakpoint` data property and set it dynamically as follows with this `getBreakpoint` method which I both call and set an event listener for on `created()`:

```
getBreakpoint () {
  // if the window width divided by 400 rounded down returns a valid index
  // 0 thru 2, return the array item, else hardcode index to 2 and return 800
  this.breakpoint = [0, 400, 800][Math.floor(window.innerWidth / 400) <= 2 ? Math.floor(window.innerWidth / 400) : 2]
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Glad things worked out for you at the end :)